# Using Javascript libraries in Curity scripts

Tags: javascript, curity

I'm getting to grips with Curity, and it looks very promising, but I need to replicate a weird hashing function from a legacy system. The built-in context class passed in to a credential transformation procedure does not include the algorithms I need, so I want to use the crypto-js library. Unfortunately, the Curity documentation is a bit light on the topic of using 3rd-party JS libraries. It says this:

> Global scripts allow the use of standard JavaScript libraries. Simply include the source code of your favourite JS library in a global script to start using it from any of your JS scripts.

But there seems to be a lot of hand-waving in those words "include the source". There's no mention of any module system, and I don't think it runs on Node, so I assume there's no support for require or import statements. Am I supposed to copy all the source code for something that is normally packaged as a module, and somehow unpack and refactor it to work as a single script file? And then do that again any time in future if I want to incorporate upstream changes? Has anyone out there done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Curity Identity Server supports extensibility via Javascript, based on Nashorn, which has some limitations, since this engine is based on ECMAScript 5.1. See [this tutorial](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/) for a good overview. There are two options for performing crypto tasks:

**USE JAVA INTEROP**

This is explained in `Invoking Java Methods from Javascript` in the above article. You should be able to get hold of a Java class that can calculate a secure hash for you. I have not tried this code but it would look something like this:

```js
var md = Java.type('java.security.MessageDigest');
var instance = md.getInstance('SHA-256');
var hashedBytes = instance.digest(utf8bytes);
```

**USE JAVASCRIPT**

You can place a script such as `mycryptolib.js` in the `global-scripts` folder:

```js
function createHash(context, input) {
  
  var output = ...
  return output;
}
```

Its functions will then be automatically available in other scripts, such as a token procedure. Just use the function name, without any `import` or `require` statements:

```js
createHash(context, 'xyz');
```

If using third party libraries you can follow the same approach, though you will need to add an ES5 third party file to the global-scripts folder. This might be called `crypto-js-es5.min.js`, and you might be able to produce the script using a tool such as Babel.

Comment: Wow, that Java interop stuff really should be mentioned in the docs. It's not the answer I was looking for, but it was exactly the answer I needed, thanks.